# Declaring resolution to ambiguous constructor reference

Tags: c#

Consider the following class

```
    class Foo
    {
        public Foo(IBar bar=null)
        {                
        }
    }
```

I have a need to inject an alternate constructor to allow the IBar instance to be provided on demand rather than injected.

```
    class Foo
    {
        public Foo(IBar bar=null)
        {                
        }

        public Foo(Func<IBar> barFunc) : this((IBar)null)
        {                
        }
    }
```

However there is a bunch of code in several dependent projects like:

```
        Foo foo = new Foo(null);
```

This code won't compile anymore due to the ambiguous constructor reference.

Obviously I could change the code to

```
        Foo foo = new Foo((IBar)null);
```

But this would require changes to a whole bunch of projects, and my goal is a transparent change. Is there some way to specify which constructor to call if ambiguous? Or a way to indicate to the compiler that barFunc cannot be null

At the moment, I am looking at this but it feels .... dirty

```
    class Foo
    {
        public Foo(IBar bar=null)
        {

        }

        public Foo(Func<IBar> barFunc, bool notUsed) : this((IBar)null)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered factory methods instead of constructors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use a static method ala named constructor idiom:

```
class Foo
{
    ...
    public static Foo Create(Func<IBar> func)
    {
        return new Foo(func());
    }
}
```

Comment: I was lamenting the lack of nameable constructors (like eg. Delphi) but of course the above approach exists and is used in singleton pattern instantiators. Your solution missed the fact that I need to change the new constructor to `private Foo(Func<IBar> barFunc) : this((IBar)null)` so legacy consumers cannot see this constructor, but the suggestion got me over the line.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `Foo(Func<IBar>)` constructor private, and add a factory method:

```
public static Foo WithIBarFunc(Func<IBar> func) {
    return new Foo(func);
}
```

If you can, delete the the `Foo(Func<IBar>)` constructor all together and write the method like this:

```
public static Foo WithIBarFunc(Func<IBar> func) {
    var foo = new Foo(null);

    // initialise foo with func...
    return foo;
}
```